# Intent-filter to peek into incoming emails?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

Is it possible to use Intent-filter to peek into incoming emails?

What I am trying to do is to parse incoming confirmation email and take some necessary actions based on the email body text.

It should work with all email clients on the device -- native email, gmail etc

Comment: Gmail or standard email?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto both -- should works for all email clients

Answer (score 1):

For gmail, this is not possible. See [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/ztAtgU1BGsA). It seems unlikely to be the case for the standard email client, from [this discussion](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEMQFjAB&url=http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/d19e1bab1d91febb&ei=awzVULGZB-nV0QHs6YD4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHKbc6tMb9ZyyxgBK7PlfxG_kTCmQ&sig2=T9KPrN58ChF5BcbGKLeBaw&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.dmQ). This sounds like something that requires writing your own client...

Answer (score 0):

[Automagic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.gridvision.ppam.androidautomagic) might offer you a temporary workaround: *"The trigger General Broadcast dynamically registers a broadcast receiver at runtime with the specified intent filter.
Please also see ..."*

[More..](http://automagic4android.com/en/help/components-triggers#trigger_general_broadcast)

Martin, Automagic's developer is quite helpfull and should be able to provide some details if the above is what you are looking for. Good luck :o)